# Unreal Android Development using AARs

Tags: android, c++, apk, unreal-engine4, aar

I've gone into Unreal/Build/Android/Java/aar-imports.txt and added my aar like so:

```
com.google.android.gms,kt-bridge,11.0.4
```

(for now I'm just using com.google.android.gms for testing purposes)

I also know that its properly being packaged into my apk because in my output log I'm getting:

```
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Extracting AAR kt-bridge-11.0.4
...
UATHelper: Packaging (Android (ASTC)): Updating project.properties, local.properties, and build.xml for kt-bridge-11.0.4...
```

now in my code I would like to get the aar and call the method "getInstance".

I've included in my .h file:
"Android/AndroidJNI.h" and "Android/AndroidApplication.h"

and in my .cpp I do:

```
#if PLATFORM_ANDROID
if (JNIEnv* Env = FAndroidApplication::GetJavaEnv())
{
     jclass foundClass = Env->FindClass("com/google/android/gms/kt-bridge");
     if (foundClass)
          return "found class";

     return "did not find class";
}
#endif
```

which results in:

```
Abort message: 'java_vm_ext.cc:534] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: JNI NewStringUTF called with pending exception java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.kt-bridge" on path: DexPathList[[directory "."],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/system/lib, /vendor/lib, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]'
```

I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong and can't seem to find any useful help online.

Answer (score 0):

may be you can use upl?
here is link
https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Platforms/Mobile/Android/AndroidConfigRulesSystem/index.html

add aar and code with upl should work

Comment: I don't believe so. I may be wrong but this seems like a way to query your device for specific hardware / software that's already running. My AAR isn't running.